# How to parse a JSON data (type : BigInt) in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, bigint

I have a simple request but It seems to be harder than expected. I have to parse a `bigint` from a JSON stream. The value is `990000000069396215`. In my code, this value is declared in TypeScript like this: `id_address: bigint`. But this is not working, the value is truncated, and return nothing like `9900000000693962100`

[image]

How can I simply manage this `bigint` in my code?

Comment: JSON notation does not support "bigint" values. Just old-school JavaScript numbers. You can represent it as a string and then turn it back into a bigint with your own code.

Comment: The JSON spec actually does not specify anything about precision of numbers, so you can technically have a bigint. However, built-in functions like `JSON.parse` will have a tough time with this since I don't see any way to change how numbers are parsed.

Comment: @Jacob yes I suppose that's true, but as far as I know all modern browsers parse JSON number strings as plain numbers.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make it reliable and clean then always stringify/parse bigint values as objects:

```
function replacer( key: string, value: any ): any {
    if ( typeof value === 'bigint' ) {
        return { '__bigintval__': value.toString() };
    }
    return value;
}

function reviver( key: string, value: any ): any {
    if ( value != null && typeof value === 'object' && '__bigintval__' in value ) {
        return BigInt( value[ '__bigintval__' ] );
    }
    return value;
}

JSON.stringify( obj, replacer );

JSON.parse( str, reviver );
```

Comment: doesn't this translate bigint val to string val?

Comment: It converts bigint to object containing string value, and back.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to do something like this,

```
export interface Address {
id_address: string;
}
```

Then somewhere in your code where you implement this interface you need to do,

```
const value = BigInt(id_address);  // I am guessing that inside your class you have spread your props and you can access id_address. So inside value you will get your Big integer value.
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) for BigInt.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't specially want a BigInt but I just want to read the value. When I try to log the value, it's already truncated. I log it like this ```JSON.stringify(value, (_, v) => typeof v === 'bigint' ? `${v}n` : v) ```.

Comment: Thanks. If your problem is resolved please accept the answer for future reference :)

Comment: It's not resolved. I use Needle to request the services and when I log value, it's already truncated... Don't know how to do